# Gettext Translation replacing decimals with commas in numbers

Tags: php

Okay here is my issue, I have inputs where users can input values, which get passed to a variable on another page. I am using gettext, so my languages are English, Chinese, Spanish and Russian. When I am using English my numbers are like so:

£23.50

But when my user changes languages to Spanish, the decimal is replaced with a comma, so the numbers are like so:

£2,350.

Are these two numbers the same? Just looking at them, doesn't look like they are, but how come my system is doing this? Is there a work around? I am setting their locals via a cookie when they choose a language to initiate gettext.

Here is my code for gettext translations:

```
include(APP."/libs/languages/libs/streams.php");
include(APP."/libs/languages/libs/gettext.php");

define('LOCALE', 'en_GB');

define('SESSION_LOCALE_KEY', 'locale');
define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_GB');
define('LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM', 'lang');
define('WEBSITE_DOMAIN', 'messages');

if (array_key_exists(LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM, $_REQUEST)) {
    $current_locale = $_REQUEST[LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM];
    $_COOKIE[SESSION_LOCALE_KEY] = $current_locale;
} elseif (array_key_exists(SESSION_LOCALE_KEY, $_COOKIE)) {
    $current_locale = $_COOKIE[SESSION_LOCALE_KEY];
} else {
    $current_locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE;
}
//will eventually stick this all in the model file
putenv("LC_ALL=$current_locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $current_locale);
bindtextdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lang');
bind_textdomain_codeset(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8');
textdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN);
```

Comment: I guess you mean `23,50` and not `2,350`? If so, then yes they are the same (when used as string). Some countries use a comma as a decimal separator and some use a point. There are also differences for thousand separators.

Comment: Nope, it actually changes them to 2,350, I've not a clue why.

Comment: I'm almost absolutely sure that `gettext()` doesn't move the decimal separator just for kicks. Then again, you didn't mention how you printed those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing LC_ALL which changes everything local, numbers etc to LC_MESSAGES which just translates my text as that is all I needed. I didn't need to localise numbers